# Splitting a vector according to a table

Tags: c++

A premise, I'm not a programmer, I'm a physicist and I use c++ as a tool to analyze data (ROOT package). My knowledge might be limited!

I have this situation, I read data from a file and store them in a vector (no problem with that)

```
vector<double> data;
```

with this data I want to plot a correlation plot, so I need to split them up in two different subsets one of which will be the X entries of a 2D histogram and the other the Y entries.

The splitting must be as follow, I have this table (I only copy a small part of it just to explain the problem)

```
************* LBA - LBC **************
--------------------------------------
Cell Name  |  Channel   |    PMT     |
D0         |          0 |          1 |
A1-L       |          1 |          2 |
BC1-R      |          2 |          3 |
BC1-L      |          3 |          4 |
A1-R       |          4 |          5 |
A2-L       |          5 |          6 |
BC2-R      |          6 |          7 |
BC2-L      |          7 |          8 |
A2-R       |          8 |          9 |
A3-L       |          9 |         10 |
A3-R       |         10 |         11 |
BC3-L      |         11 |         12 |
BC3-R      |         12 |         13 |
D1-L       |         13 |         14 |
D1-R       |         14 |         15 |
A4-L       |         15 |         16 |
BC4-R      |         16 |         17 |
BC4-L      |         17 |         18 |
A4-R       |         18 |         19 |
A5-L       |         19 |         20 |
...
None       |         31 |         32 |
```

as you can see there are entries like `A1-L` and `A1-R` which corresponds to the left and right side of one **cell**, to this left and right side are associated an `int` that corresponds to a **channel**, in this case 1 and 4. I wish these left and right side to be on the X and Y axis of my 2D histogram.

The problem is then to associate to the vector of data somehow this table so that I can pick the channels that belongs to the same cell and put them one on the X axis and the other on the Y axis. To complicate the things there are also cells that don't have a partner like in this example `D0` and channels that don't have a cell associated like channel 31.

---

My attempted solution is to create an indexing vector

```
vector<int> indexing = (0, 1, 4, ....);
```

and an ordered data vector

```
vector<double> data_ordered;
```

and fill the ordered vector with something like

```
for( vector<int> iterator it = indexing.begin(); it != indexing.end(); ++it)
    data_ordered.push_back(data.at(*it));
```

and then put the even index of `data_ordered` on the X axis and the odd values on the Y axis but I have the problem of the `D0` cell and the empty ones!

Another idea that I had is to create a `struct` like

```
struct cell{
    string cell_name;
    int left_channel;
    int right_channel;
    double data;
    ....
    other informations
};
```

and then try to work with that, but there it comes my lack of c++ knowledge! Can someone give me an hint on how to solve this problem? I hope that my question is clear enough and that it respects the rules of this site!

EDIT----------

To clarify the problem I try to explain it with an example

```
vector<double> data = (data0, data1, data2, data3, data4, ...);
```

do `data0` has index 0 and if I go to the table I see it corresponds to the `cell D0` which has no other partner and let's say can be disregarded for now. `data1` has index 1 and it corresponds to the left part of the `cell A1` (`A1-L`) so I need to find the right partner which has index 4 in the table and ideally leads me to pick `data4` from the vector containing the data.
I hope this clarify the situation at least a little!

Comment: What does `PMT` have to do with this problem?  In your original `vector` `data`, how does that order of elements relate to the table you posted?  Is `Channel` the index into the original `vector<double> data` for a given field?  In your *final* output (nevermind intermediate stuff), what do you want to be done with the data for `D0`?  Not displayed?  Do you want or need the cell name for your final output?  Other than the fact that your table is ordered by `Channel`, does that table's order matter for display purposes?  What program do you use to compile, and what version?

Comment: would be nice to see the original data in the vector and how it corresponds to the table you have. I.e is the first record in the vector[0] = D001? and you have to split them etc?

Comment: So what *should* be done with those unpaired and empty cells?

Comment: `PMT` = `Channel +1` so they are correlated the solution for one also is the solution for the other. In the original `vector data` I'm not sure about the order but it is convention here to assume that it is the same as in the `Channel` field of the table as you stated! the data for `D0` alone constitutes one `cell` that is formed by two `channels` so it have to be displayed somehow. Would be nice to keep the cell name but not essential! The order of the table is not important, what matters is the `Channel` to `cell` relation. I use gcc version 4.1.2. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @SD1990 The original data are values that are in no way correlated to to anything in the table, they are like 1.23 or 123.453 etc..

Comment: ok so you then want to split this data? into the structure of the table above? sorry its hard to understand from what youve written, although im not a physicist

Comment: @n.m. The unpaired and empty cell if are a big problem can be disregarded for now.

Comment: Where does the table come from? Is it a text file, or what?

Comment: @Beta it comes from here http://zenis.dnp.fmph.uniba.sk/tile.html but I have written a python tool to parse it and can save it in a text file or use python to manipulate it.

Comment: Sort the rows like in your proposed solution, but don't use even and odd indices, look at ith cell name and compare it with the (i+1)th. If they differ in the last character only and it's L and R respectively, treat them like a pair, then increment i by 2. Otherwise it's an unpaired/empty cell, increment i by 1.

Comment: Do you know how to parse the table with C++?

Comment: Splitting the first column in two (the cell name and the L/R/nothing indicator) would be helpful. In this case you just compare the names for equality.

Comment: @Beta No but I guess I can look for that on google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an engine that does what you want, roughly:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum sub_entry { left, right, only };

struct DataType {
  std::string cell;
  sub_entry sub;
  DataType( DataType const& o ): cell(o.cell), sub(o.sub) {};
  DataType( const char* c, sub_entry s=only ):
    cell( c ),
    sub( s )
  {}
  DataType(): cell("UNUSED"), sub(only) {};
  // lexographic weak ordering:
  bool operator<( DataType const& o ) const {
    if (cell != o.cell)
      return cell < o.cell;
    return sub < o.sub;
  }
};

typedef std::vector< double > RawData;
typedef std::vector< DataType > LookupTable;
typedef std::map< DataType, double > OrganizedData;

OrganizedData organize( RawData const& raw, LookupTable const& table )
{
  OrganizedData retval;
  for( unsigned i = 0; i < raw.size() && i < table.size(); ++i ) {
    DataType d = table[i];
    retval[d] = raw[i];
  }
  return retval;
}

void PrintOrganizedData( OrganizedData const& data ) {
  for (OrganizedData::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it ) {
    std::cout << (*it).first.cell;
    switch( (*it).first.sub ) {
      case left: {
        std::cout << "-L";
      } break;
      case right: {
        std::cout << "-R";
      } break;
      case only: {
      } break;
    }
    std::cout << " is " << (*it).second << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  RawData test;
  test.push_back(3.14);
  test.push_back(2.8);
  test.push_back(-1);
  LookupTable table;
  table.resize(3);
  table[0] = DataType("A1", left);
  table[1] = "D0";
  table[2] = DataType("A1", right);
  OrganizedData org = organize( test, table );
  PrintOrganizedData( org );
}
```

The lookup table stores what channel maps to what cell name and side.

Unused entries in the lookup table should be set to `DataType()`, which will flag their values to be stored in an `"UNUSED"` location.  (It will still be stored, but you can discard it afterwards).

The result of this is a map from `(CellName, Side)` to the `double` data.  I included a simple printer that just dumps the data.  If you have graphing software, you can figure out a way to make a graph from it.  Skipping `"UNUSED"` is an exercise that involves checking `(*it).first.cell == "UNUSED"` in that printing loop.

I believe everything is C++03 compliant.  A bunch of the above becomes prettier if you had a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Ok I see some things that I don't understand like what is the DataType() : .... {}; syntax? (sorry for my ignorance! I'm trying to learn) can you point me somewhere I can read about this? Thanks so much for the effort! I will accept the answer now and try to learn form it!

Comment: @drkg4b that is a constructor.  C++ allows you to create types that behave like built-in types.  In this case, `DataType` can be constructed from either a string, or from a string and an enum.  It supports `operator<`, which lets us sort it and store it as a key to a `std::map`.  I used the `std::map` to store the results, which means that the left/right entries will be clumped adjacent to each other in it -- and with that `enum` you get the possibility that there are "lone" items as well.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I really need to learn using these struct!